# How Can I Vertically Align Text in a MultiCol Table Cell So That It Doesn't Touch Top Of Cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

I've just created a table usig LaTeX, but cannot position text within a cell the way I would like to. Specifically, in a multi-row cell, the very top of characters in the top line of text touches the top line of the table, making the text slightly harder to read. The code I've used is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{specifics}{{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\BODY\end{minipage}}\par\noindent}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tabular}{||p{10em}|p{10em}|p{10em}||}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3} {||c||}{ Title} \\
        \hline
        \hline
        \shortstack{Top Col\\Number 1} & Col 2 & Col 3\\
        \hline \hline
        \rowcolor{lightgray}
        R1 C1 & R1 C2 & R1 C3\\
        \hline
        R2 C1 & R2 C2 & R2 C3\\
        \hline 
        \rowcolor{lightgray}
        R3 C1 & R3 C2 & R3 C3\\ 
        \hline 
        R4 C1 & R4 C2 & R4 C3 \\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{lightgray}
        R5 C1 & R5 C2 & R5 C3\\
        \hline \hline   
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And it results in this table:
[image: My Table]

How can I reposition "Top Col 1" so that the 'T' and the 'C' do not touch the top line of the table?

Comment: `\shortstack{\rule{0pt}{10pt}Top Col\\Number 1}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following (without `shortstack`, used `\extrarowheight` and `m` column type in the first table column):

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\rowcolors{3}{lightgray}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{||m{10em}|p{10em}|p{10em}||}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3} {||c||}{ Title} \\
        \hline
        \hline
        Top Col\newline Number 1    
                & Col 2 & Col 3\\
        \hline \hline

        R1 C1   & R1 C2 & R1 C3\\
        \hline
        R2 C1   & R2 C2 & R2 C3\\
        \hline

        R3 C1   & R3 C2 & R3 C3\\
        \hline
        R4 C1   & R4 C2 & R4 C3 \\
        \hline

        R5 C1 & R5 C2 & R5 C3\\
        \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {||m{10em}|t{10em}|t{10em}||},
    row{odd} = {lightgray},
    row{1} = {white},
  }
  \hline
    \SetCell[c=3]{c} Title & & \\
  \hline\hline
    {Top Col\\Number 1} & Col 2 & Col 3\\
  \hline\hline
        R1 C1           & R1 C2 & R1 C3\\
  \hline
        R2 C1           & R2 C2 & R2 C3\\
  \hline
        R3 C1           & R3 C2 & R3 C3\\
  \hline
        R4 C1           & R4 C2 & R4 C3\\
  \hline
        R5 C1           & R5 C2 & R5 C3\\
  \hline\hline
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]